# Is there a depend destroy block in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dependencies

I've got a huge model with a lot dependencies.

```
has_many :names, dependent: :destroy
has_many :links, dependent: :destroy
has_many :fruits, dependent: :destroy
has_many :images, dependent: :destroy
has_many :houses, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
has_many :cars, dependent: :destroy
has_many :places, dependent: :destroy
has_many :statistics, dependent: :destroy
```

Is there a possibility to wrap it with a "depend: destroy"-block for more clarity?

This is just an example. In my model are 34 connected models.

Comment: `wrap it with a "depend: destroy"`. wrap what?

Comment: `depent: destroy do
    has_many :names
    has_many :links
    has_many :fruits
end`

For example

Comment: what do you want to do in that callback?